# make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y seems to hang

Tags: build, kernel, message

Building a 3.4.x kernel for an android phone on Ubuntu using Linaro 4.7 toolchain.

Porting over governors from another device with good success so far.

The latest one builds with the corrected code, but at the end I get the `make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y` message.

I ran `make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y` so I can try to see what was wrong, but it gets to `arch/arm/vfp/entry.o` and just sits there.

I have waited a while for further output, but since I have never had to do a mismatch debug I am not aware of normal behavior.

Should I keep waiting?  Or kill it and try something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, made clean and re-ran it.  Went through.